# Are there ordinals other than the set of natural numbers which satisfy this property?

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals

Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal. We say that $\alpha$ is good iff for every $\beta\in \alpha$, there exists $\gamma\in \alpha$ such that $|\scr{P}(\beta)|\leq |\gamma|$.

Question: Is the set of natural numbers the only good ordinal ?

Thank you

Comment: I *think* $\omega$ is the only one you can prove in unaugmented ZFC, but that this is true for several types of large cardinal? Doubtless Asaf will correct me or elaborate.

Comment: @Malice: Let me correct you. :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks! I never have learned as much as I should about proper ordinals...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the empty set also satisfies this, as do any strong limit cardinal.

Note that this condition says that $\lambda<\kappa\implies2^\lambda<\kappa$.

It is easy to show there is a proper class of strong limit cardinals, and if you are familiar with $\beth$ numbers, then the limit $\beth$'s are strong limit cardinals.

Comment: Thanks Asaf. I am not familiar with $\beth$ numbers. What are they called ? (so that I can search for them on google)

Comment: Beth numbers. Beth is the second letter of the Hebrew alphabet, after Aleph.

Comment: OK, found them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ahhhh. So we just take the union of $\beth_0,\beth_1,...$

Comment: Yes, for example. Or any $\beth_\delta$ for a limit ordinal $\delta$.

Comment: Yes. OK  I see. ${}{}{}{}$